# Pass values to JS function MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => ts.Break, 
    new { @onblur = "updateBreak(this,modelItem =>ts.ID)" })
```

In above code how I can pass `ts.ID` to `updateBreak()`?

Above code not working.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With Razor, you can display the properties of your viewmodel using @ character, like *@YourViewModel.PropertyYouWantToUse*

In your case, you can use *@ts.ID* (don't forget the simple quote for a string parameter passed to a javascript function), like this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => ts.Break, 
    new { @onblur = "updateBreak(this,'"+@ts.ID+"')" })
```

Because the string is client side, you need to build your string server side, so you have to use string concatenation, using plus characters.

*"updateBreak(this,'@ts.ID')"* will display *"updateBreak(this,'@ts.ID')*, so you need to write this : *"updateBreak(this,'"+@ts.ID+"')"*

Comment: The string is server side not client side. You need to build the string server side using +

Comment: @randy More information provided. Better ? :)

Comment: @Bhupendra S Rao Welcome, my pleasure ;)